# Python Java Integration for Graph implementation

Tags: java, python, continuous-integration

Hi every one I have to  create a graph and calculate page rank of the each node .I have written code in python to create a graph  now i would like to integrate that code into Java so that i can run my application to run dynamically in which i have to display graph attributes of each node like page rank ,in degree ,out_degree of a node.Kindly help Thanks

Comment: Please add your python code to your post.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jython libraries for using the python code in java programs . you can follw the link 
http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html#using-jython-within-java-applications

Comment: Hi thanks i could find the procedure to integrate python with java by adding jython jar to my class path but  i am getting the following error when i run using eclipse                                                         *sys-package-mgr*: can't create package cache dir, '/home/464028/jython-2.5.jar/jython-2.5.jar/cachedir/packages'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/464028/Desktop/PageRank2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import glob,json, os,re,sys
ImportError: No module named glob

Comment: This error may come because of the JYTHON_HOME is not defined in system variable and also add jython.jar in your java build path

Comment: Thank you  so much i could rectify this .

Comment: Hi I have created a web application in which i have to specify the location of raw data and  i need to parse the data using python script written a text file.My python script will generate a  graph through which i am writing the  users info a to a file and display to jsp .I do not prefer to use any local file system to save the results or any script .How do i save all these files to my web application folder.and access ...Thanks